# css menu active without jquery

Tags: html, css

How to add active class without jquery. I have sourced menu in simple css but i want active in different color. Could any body help me to add the active class to the menu

```
 #menu ul{
         margin: 0;padding: 0;
         list-style-type: none;
         font-family: verdana, arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         }
#menu li { 
         margin: 0 0 0px 0; 
         display: inline; float: left; 
         margin-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
         }
#menu a{
       display: block; padding: 5px 10px; 
       width: 100px; border-right: 2px solid #ffffff; 
       text-decoration: none;  border-left: 10px solid #1958b7;  
       color: #fff; background: #2175bc;
       }
#menu a:hover{
             color: pink; background: #2586d7;   
             border-left: 10px solid #1c64d1; 
             }
```

My intention is not active class; but when user click the tab, the color of the tab to be changed from hover color. So that i will not mention any active class in html body.

Comment: Can you just use the `:active` pseudo-class in CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

### CSS

```css
#menu a:active {
    color: pink; background: #2586d7;   
    border-left: 10px solid #1c64d1; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
document.getElementById("menu").className = "Active";
```

Or edit any other attribute like this.

Comment: Good job on that answer. People tend to forget that jQuery is just a JavaScript framework afterall... It's not a damn Bible !

Comment: Yes, but this will only add an `active` class to the menu, but not an `li` element within, so seems a bit redundant?

Comment: No but you can probably assume the OP was looking for a none JavaScript method of doing this.

Comment: Reading over the OP again I must agree with @defaultNINJA, I read it in a javascript mindset. Try :active

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you're implementing this, on a static site, you can just change the structure of the `<li>` that you want to be active, to:

`<li class="active">`

And then in your `CSS`

`#menu li.active a { background:red; color:#fff; }`

and if you want `active` and `hover` to be the same:

```
#menu a:hover, 
#menu li.active a { 
    background:red; color:#fff; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it functionally in javascript *without* jQuery.

I'm taking into account that you want only one menu item to be active at a time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function menuItemClicked(sender, event)
    {
      var menuItem = sender;

      //we need to get rid of the item that was active before
      var menuitems = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
      for (var i = 0; i < menuitems.length; i++) 
      {
        //if this ul is a menu item
        if (menuitems[i].className.indexOf("menuitem") != -1) 
        {
          //reset its classname.
          menuitems[i].className = "menuitem";
        }
      }

      //and now we add the "active" class to the item we clicked.
      menuItem.className = dmenuItem.className + " active";
    }
</script>


<ul>
  <li class="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked(this, event)">I am a menu item</li>
  <li class="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked(this, event)">I am a menu item too</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList) in [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/classlist).

Here are the faster native versions of jQuery class manipulation:

```
.addClass(className)     element.classList.add(className)
.removeClass(className)  element.classList.remove(className)
.toggleClass(className)  element.classList.toggle(className)
.hasClass(className)     element.classList.contains(className)
```

**Note:** see how ineffective is [jQuery 1.10.1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js)

```
hasClass: function( selector ) {
  var className = " " + selector + " ",
    i = 0,
    l = this.length;
  for ( ; i < l; i++ ) {
    if ( this[i].nodeType === 1 && (" " + this[i].className + " ").replace(rclass, " ").indexOf( className ) >= 0 ) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```